# iOS Capacitor launch screen resizes during launch

Tags: ios, capacitor, ionic5

I am developing an iOS app using Ionic. I have a problem with the splash screen which I'm trying to resolve either from the native side via Xcode or from the Ionic side.

I used `cordova-res ios --skip-config --copy` to generate and set the images and made sure they are there in Xcode.

When the app launches, the splash screen consists of first a native image displayed by iOS then an "identical" copy of it by Capacitor while the app loads. However, the second screen appears smaller.

How can I make the two sizes match? I wouldn't care if the solution scales the image up or down, as long as they become the same size.

I am comfortable with Ionic but not comfortable with Xcode or Swift, so please be as clear as you possibly can if the solution is on the Xcode side :).

Video of the problem: https://youtu.be/DIfjErgw7hU